# How to make addView() cheaper

Tags: android, performance, layout-inflater, jank

I have an activity that measures how long does animate/layout/measure/etc of layout takes.

```
class RenderingMeasureActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.skeleton)

        val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.simple, root, false)
        root.postDelayed({
            root.addView(view)
        }, 5000)
    }
}
```

Skeleton layout is nothing but `FrameLayout` with `match_parent` and id `root`. Simple layout is just:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="ahoj"
        android:textSize="32sp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

In the activity, I have delayed `addView()` so I am sure I am measuring just that and no other influence is there.

Now, whatever I do, the measurements are off the charts. It takes at least 17ms (average more like 25ms) which is definite source of JANK (>16.7ms). Longest duration is Command Issue and I get same results from `FrameMetrics`, gpu profiling bars and similar duration also from **systrace**.

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible that `addView` (or `inflate`) of **any** layout is so expensive that Android SDK apps will always have JANK? Why, if the same layout (merged into one) is set in `setContentView()`, it takes less time (not by much though)?

P.S.: I tried other layouts, such as constraint, linear, relative. Merge tag helps **a little**, but is not always usable.
P.P.S.: Creating layout programmatically has no effect as I have separated  inflating part.

Comment: so your problem is that `LayoutInflater` takes too much time? and UI thread freezes?

Comment: @pskink no, `LayoutInflater` is separate process. I care about `addView`. It is not really a problem, I am just curious if it's normal, that any dynamically added view causes jank. And if not, then what is problem with the code.

Comment: it depends on what you are adding: if it is just a `View` (like `ImageView` or `TextView`) it should be light fast, but if it is a `ViewGroup` (like any layout) it may need complex measure/layout phases

Comment: @pskink Alright thanks, that does make sense, though I am just surprised it is so much. As you can see in question, it is just one FrameLayout (one layout pass) with one TextView child. So I would guess it should be definitely less than 16ms.

Comment: hmmm, i agree `FrameLayout`'s measurement / layout code should be much faster than `RelativeLayout` / `ConstraintLayout` - how exactly do you get those ms numbers?

Comment: @pskink Developer options > profile rendering gpu as bars. It is always above 16ms line. For precise numbers I use `FrameMetrics` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/FrameMetrics
It is actually much faster then Relative/Constraint, I am more concerned about the duration itself then comparison between types of ViewGroup.